# How to move a value from rax to a label?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to move the value in rax to the label I created. Essentially I'm trying to figure out what I should add to `mov label, rax` to make it work. Currently my label is declared as a quadword, but that can change. So far I've tried:

`mov [label], rax` - This compiles, but when I go to link it gives me a "Relocation truncated to fit error"

`movq [label], rax` - this will not compile

`movq label, rax` - this will also not compile

`mov [label], [rax]` - will not compile.

The ones that won't compile give me "invalid combination of opcode and operands". What am I supposed to do?

EDIT: fuz answered it in the comments. 'mov [rel label], rax' works. Thank you!

Comment: Try `mov [rel label], rax`.

Comment: The devil is in the details. Include your code, then it will probably become more evident for anyone attempting to help.

Comment: What storage does `label` point to? (must be qword at least)

Comment: You can use `default rel` if you don't feel like writing `rel` all the time.

Comment: @Shift_Left: Yes in general a better [mcve] would be good, but I can tell from the "Relocation truncated to fit error" that they're  trying to link on Linux with a gcc configured with default-pie.  (Or some other platform where the linker gives the same error message for 32-bit absolute relocations).  I think on MacOS it wouldn't have assembled in the first place (not representable in the MachO object file).  Windows has a largeaddressaware flag that you can use to link executables to ASLR in the low 32 bits, although it's probably off by default so you'd get a similar error.

Comment: @PeterCordes That level of detail is beyond the scope of my experience and the only time I've encountered that is when I've attempted to write a 32 bit value into a 16 bit register. It is for that reason I didn't blurt out a solution as there just wasn't enough information.

Comment: @Shift_Left: My point was that with the right experience / expertise, this does happen to be enough information, even though it doesn't look that way.  In your case your "value" was probably a symbol address like `mov ax, label`?  Yeah that would require truncating a relocation on linking into an executable when it turned out to be outside the low 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern printf

section .data
    output db "%lld",10,0

section .bss
    num1: resq 1

section .text
    global main

main:
    push rbp

    mov rax, 666
    mov [num1], rax

    xor rax, rax
    mov rdi, output
    mov rsi, [num1]
    call printf

    pop rbp
    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

Compile and linking:

> $ nasm -felf64 main.s && gcc -no-pie main.o
>
> $ ./a.out
>
> 666

Comment: That requires `-no-pie`.  Also try explaining what you changed to solve OPs problem.

Comment: Why would you want 32-bit absolute `[disp32]` addressing modes instead of using `default rel` for RIP-relative?  You only want `[disp32 + reg]` or scaled index for indexing a static array, not for a bare label.  [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427).  This works but it's *not* a good recommendation.  There are many ways to do things in asm and this is one strictly worse than choices.  (I'd be happy to change my downvote to an upvote if/when you improve this answer.  Don't take it personally and welcome to Stack Overflow)